# React useEffect and useState problems

Tags: reactjs, use-effect

I am trying to create a simple React front-end for a smart contract which is a To-Do List. My problem is with the `useEffect` hook. I am trying to do a for loop inside the effect hook, and putting the results into the toDoTask state. While I managed to print my results on screen, they do not show on the console (shows an empty array like the initial value). And when I try to add the todoTask state as a dependency (to check the changes, when I add new tasks), the loop goes infinite. I don't know what is the problem actually, here is the code:

```
function App() {   

 const [todoTask, setTodoTask] =  useState([]);
 const [web3, setWeb3] =  useState(undefined);
 const [accounts, setAccounts] =  useState(undefined);
 const [contract, setContract] =  useState(undefined);  
 const [taskCount, setTaskCount] =  useState(0); 

// HERE I HAVE HAD ANOTHER EFFECT HOOK TO CONNECT BLOCKCHAIN, I'VE REMOVED IT FOR SIMPLICITY 

useEffect(() => {
const todoInit = async () => {

  const taskCount = await contract.methods.taskCount().call();
  setTaskCount(taskCount);

  for (var i = 1; i <= taskCount; i++) {
    const task =  await contract.methods.tasks(i).call();
    setTodoTask(prevArray => [...prevArray, task.content]); // task is an object, i'm getting the content(text basically)
  } 
  console.log(taskCount); // This works fine
  console.log(todoTask);   // This returns an empty array   
}      
if(typeof web3 !== 'undefined' && typeof accounts !== 'undefined' && typeof contract !== 'undefined') {
  todoInit();          
}    
}, [web3, accounts, contract])
```

Comment: not related to blockchain

Comment: Updating state is asynchonous, so the change is not immidiately visible. The actual state variable gets updated later. Why do you care about printing it in the console when the result shows up on the page?

Comment: You can just add another `useEffect` with only `todoTask` as it's dependency if you want to keep track of it's changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't log a state variable just setted because `setTodoTask` is async.

Much better use another `useEffect`:

```
useEffect(() => {
   console.log(todoTask);
}, [todoTask]);
```

This should log the very last value of `todoTask`.

Note: the fact that `console.log(taskCount);` works fine it's just a case (maybe due to the fact that `for` takes a lot of time and `setTaskCount` will be resolved before).

Comment: First of all thank you for the answer, that's very helpful. Could you suggest someting about the infinite loop? I mean, i want it to be updated when i add new stuff to the  Todo array, but putting it to the dependency array makes the hook go insane. And again, thank you for the help i will accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I do not see the need of using `taskCount` as a state. Could it be just a variable? Meaning of removing`const [taskCount, setTaskCount] =  useState(0);` the function could look this way:

```js
useEffect(() => {
    const todoInit = async () => {
      const tasks = await contract.methods.taskCount().call();
      tasks.map(async (element, index) => {
        const task = await contract.methods.tasks(index).call();
        setTodoTask((prevArray) => [...prevArray, task.content]); // task is an object, i'm getting the content(text basically)
      });
      console.log(tasks); // This works fine
    };

    if (
      typeof web3 !== "undefined" &&
      typeof accounts !== "undefined" &&
      typeof contract !== "undefined"
    ) {
      todoInit();
    }
  }, [web3, accounts, contract]);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(todoTask);
  }, [todoTask]);
```

Also, if the reason behind having this condition `if(typeof web3 !== 'undefined' && typeof accounts !== 'undefined' && typeof contract !== 'undefined')`  - is to run only once, then you could use it like empty array `,[])` in the end and get rid of the checking `undefined` types.
You can check how to run `useEffect` only once, [here](https://css-tricks.com/run-useeffect-only-once/#the-trick-is-that-useeffect-takes-a-second-parameter)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Actually i'm just trying out the functions and stuff, that's the reason i'm using `taskCount` as a state variable. `if(typeof web3 !== 'undefined' && typeof accounts !== 'undefined' && typeof contract !== 'undefined')` is just a checker, to see if we are still connected to the blockchain. But i could not manage to run `tasks.map` function. `tasks` are only defined in the blockchain side of the code, so i think if i will map it, i need to assing it to an instance first.